# Problem while I tried to deploy lwc component to org

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

Javascript

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { showToastEvent } from 'lightning/plateformShowToastEvent';
export default class MyApp extends LightningElement {
    handleAlertClick() {
            this.showNotification();
        }
        // create showtoastEvent Object using new keyowrd
    showNotification() {
        const evt = new showToastEvent({
            title: 'Title',
            message: 'successfully exicuted',
            variant: 'success',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

HTML File

```
<template>
    <lightning-button variant="blue" label="click me" onclick={handleAlertClick} ></lightning-button>
</template>
```

Metadata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the text as text, not a screenshot, and ensure you include the whole message. I would suspect there's some inappropriate schema mapping going on, but leave it to someone else familiar with VSCode to reply (I use Illuminated Cloud + IDEA).

Comment: Including a screenshot which does not truncate the error message would be more helpful.

Comment: Seems like a proxy issue, refer this question from stackoverflow with similar error message: [All of my .json files have problems loading reference/schema from schemastore.azurewebsites.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056000/all-of-my-json-files-have-problems-loading-reference-schema-from-schemastore-az)

Comment: "http.proxy": "http://username:password@hostname:port/",
"http.proxyAuthorization": null,
"http.proxyStrictSSL": true

Comment: "what to write in place of http.proxy"                                                         
 "http.proxy": "http://username:password@hostname:port/",
"http.proxyAuthorization": null,
"http.proxyStrictSSL": true

Comment: can u please take remote access of my laptop through zoom.

Comment: i am still facing the same issue. please help